# Building an edit/update database form - adding column

Tags: php, html

I am working on an update database record form. The data is fetched from db table and populated into an html table on the webpage. I am stuck now how to add another column (5th) in the table that will contains 'edit' href link for updating database script.

Like:

```
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Edit|
| -- | -- | -- | -- |href|
```

I know this is very basic question, but so far I am not able to solve it.

It will be very helpful if someone can help me to work it.

Here is my code:

```
  <div id="update" class="col mb-4"> 

      <?php

        class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
            function __construct($it) {
                parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
            }

            function current() {
                return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
            }

            function beginChildren() {
                echo "<tr>";
            }   

            function endChildren() {
                echo "</tr>" . "\n";
            }
        } 

        echo "<table class='table-bordered'>";
        echo "<thead class='table-dark'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2<th>Col3</th><th>xCol4</th></tr>";
        echo "</thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col14 FROM table");
            $stmt->execute();

            // set the resulting array to associative
            $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {       
                echo $v;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        // $conn = null;

        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";

        ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: What's `new TableRows`? And what's up with the usage of `RecursiveArrayIterator`?

Comment: new TableRows is the instance of class defined above that extends RecursiveIteratorIterator. How to use RecursiveIteratorIterator to add another column ? I have been using it to implement the results fetched from the db only.

Comment: The indentation was off so I missed that. I'm actually having a hard time understanding the point of that class at all? I'm probably missing something, but why don't you simply do a foreach or while loop on the result and output the HTML in the loop? Then it would have been super simple to add a new `<td>`. Looks like a very complicated way of doing something very simple.

Comment: I agree. I started using this as a starter template from w3schools and keep using it because I did not find a need to re-consider earlier.

Comment: Try and avoid outputting HTML using PHP if you can. It's usually better to make a loop, end the PHP block, write your HTML and use `<?= $somevariable ?>` when you need to output something. It makes the code cleaner and IDE's can deal with syntax highlighting much better (which makes it easier to spot issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very overcomplicated, which is what's making it hard to modify.

It seems like you just want to do a simple table with data from a database. You could basically just do:

```
<div id="update" class="col mb-4"> 

    <table class='table-bordered'>
        <thead class='table-dark'>
            <tr>
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>Col2</th>
                <th>Col3</th>
                <th>Col4</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col14 FROM table");
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['Col1'] ?></td>
                    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['Col2'] ?></td>
                    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['Col3'] ?></td>
                    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['Col4'] ?></td>
                    <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><a href="some-path-somewhere/">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

I would also recommending moving the database query away from the view into a class or something. Then the view would be much cleaner (no try/catch etc). Then all the PHP in the view would be something like:

```
<?php foreach ($myClass->getTheData() as $row) : ?>

    <tr>
        <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['Col1'] ?></td>
        <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['Col2'] ?></td>
        <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['Col3'] ?></td>
        <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><?= $row['Col4'] ?></td>
        <td style='width:150px;border:1px solid grey;'><a href="some-path-somewhere/">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Now it would be much easier to change the HTML.

Comment: Can you please put a link to some example/guide of how to split code into probably MVC format, as you mentioned moving database query to other file.

Comment: There isn't one single way of doing that. There are many so you need to do some research and see what way fits you the best. I would recommend looking into some framework. No reason to reinvent the wheel. There are _plenty_ to choose from. Do some research, test some and use the one that fits you the best.